# Ubuntu issues when moving hard disk to new system

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, disk-cloning

I'm working on a legacy project with a small single board computer running Ubuntu 10.04 on a compact flash card. I need to be able to save away a working image (via dd) and copy said image to other compact flash cards for use in other single board computers (with identical hardware)

I'm able to copy the image to other flash cards and bootup on other systems no problem. But I'm seeing strange behavior. For instance, I can't use sudo on the new system (“sudo: must be setuid root”). I've gone down the path of trying to fix this, but have run into a slew of other issues.

General question is: what do I need to be aware of when moving a hard disk containing Ubuntu (in my case a compact flash card) to another computer? I was hoping it would be seamless to Ubuntu since it's moving to a system with identical hardware. Is there something that needs to be done to make it "portable"?

Comment: You may get better answers from either [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). That said, are you dd-ing the partition or the disk, and who are you doing it as (user or root)?

Comment: dd'ing the whole disk using sudo... sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=image.img bs=1M. sdb is how the compact flash shows up when using a compact flash burner.

Comment: I would guess your problem is that your usb stick has a fat32 file system. I doubt that fat32 can deal with suid. Try using a drive formatted to ext3.

Answer (score 0):

I would be more tempted to plug the cf reader in to a desktop and use ghost or partimage etc to make the duplicate on the other flash drive.  it would also give you a solid backup of the working disk vs a renamed system that may have been edited for another machine.